# Continuous functions and Embedding

Tags: general-topology

Given a function $h: X \rightarrow Y$, define the graph function $\Gamma_{h}: X \rightarrow X \times Y$ by setting $\Gamma_{h}(x) = (x,h(x))$. Giving $\Gamma_{h}(X)$ the subspace topology in $X \times Y$, show that if $h$ is continuous then $\Gamma_h$ is an embedding.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show that $\Gamma_h:X\to\Gamma_h(X)$ is continuous and has a continuous inverse?

Comment: Well we know that h is continuous. In addition, we also know that the projection function $\pi_{x}: X \times Y \rightarrow X$ is continuous, so we know the inverse of $\Gamma_{h}$ is continous as well.

Comment: Okay. And what can you say about continuity of $\Gamma_h$?

Comment: $\Gamma_{h}$ is continuous because it is a composition of continuous functions: the identity function and h, which is said to be continuous.

Comment: But I wouldn't call it a "composition" of continuous functions. I would rather say: Its components are the continuous functions $\text{Id}_X$ and $h$. So if you know that a function with continuous components is itself continuous, then you are are finished.

Comment: Is the only condition that $\Gamma_{h}$ is an embedding if it is homeomorphic?

Comment: Yes, $\Gamma_h$ is called an embedding if it is a homeomorphism onto its image. As you noted, the projection $\pi_X:X\times Y\to X$ is continuous, so its restriction to $\Gamma_h(X)$, which is the inverse of $\Gamma_h$, is continuous.

Comment: I voted to reopen, because you have shown in the comments that you have thought about the problem and, practically, already got to a solution. Sorry for not retracting my close vote in time to prevent the question from being closed. Once this is reopened, you could even write an own answer to your question (MSE explicitly allows user to answer their own questions.)

Answer (score 1):

To show that $\Gamma_h$ is an embedding we nee to show that it's continuous and injective.

Let $W = \bigcup_{i\in I} (U_i \times V_i)$ where $U_i$ is open in $X$, $V_i$ is open in $Y$.  So $W$ is any open set in $X \times Y$.  Well, $\Gamma_h^{-1}(W) = \bigcup_{i\in I} \Gamma_h^{-1}(U_i \times V_i) = \bigcup \{x \in X \ s.t. \ \Gamma_h(x) \in U_i \times V_i\}$.  But $\Gamma_h(x) \in U_i \times V_i \iff (x, h(x)) \in U_i \times V_i \iff x \in U_i \text{ and } h(x) \in V_i$  This is $\iff x \in U_i \text{ and } x \in h^{-1}(V_i)$.  Thus $\Gamma_h^{-1}(W) = $ an open set.

If $(x, h(x)) = (y, h(y))$, then clearly they're both equal, so $\Gamma_h$ is injective.

Comment: You also need to show that $\Gamma_h$ is an open map or that its inverse is continuous. Since its inverse is just the restriction to the graph of the projection to $X$, this is trivial or easy, depending on what’s already been proved. Note that in the proof of continuity you needn’t look at an arbitrary open $W$: it’s sufficient to consider basic open sets in the product.

Comment: @Brian Could you state that formally, please?  That in this case we only need to show continuity of $\Gamma_h$ on each basis element?

Comment: That’s a general fact. If $f:X\to Y$, and $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for the topology on $Y$, then $f$ is continuous iff $f^{-1}[B]$ is open in $X$ for each $B\in\mathscr{B}$.